# pdfmake - Get PDF like jsPDF function output()

Tags: android, cordova, pdf, jspdf, pdfmake

I am using pdfmake to generate a PDF client side. It's working great on Chrome: I get a base64 encoded URL that opens in a new tab.

However, on my Cordova app on android, it does not work so I want to write the PDF to the device. When I use jsPDF doc.output(), I manage to write the pdf to file in this format:

```
%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page... etc
```

Does anyone know how to get this PDF code with pdfmake?

Answer (score 0):

So after giving a second look at pdfmake.js, I managed to write my PDF to file on the android device by using this code:

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBase64(function(base64){
   // Decode base64 enocded PDF
   pdf = atob(base64);
   console.log(pdf);
   // Write to device
   window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
});
```